# extract words from a text file and print netxt line

Tags: python-3.x, list, python-requests

**sample input**

in parsing a text file .txt = `["'blah.txt'", "'blah1.txt'", "'blah2.txt'" ]`

the expected output in another text file out_path.txt

```
blah.txt 
blah1.txt
blah2.txt
```

Code that I tried, this just appends "[]" to the input file. While I also tried perl one liner replacing double and single quotes.

```
read_out_fh = open('out_path.txt',"r")

for line in read_out_fh:

    for word in line.split():

        curr_line = re.findall(r'"(\[^"]*)"', '\n')

        print(curr_line)
```

Comment: format your question with actual result and expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this happens because while you reading a file it will be taken as string and not as a list even if u kept the formatting of a list. thats why you getting [] while doing re.`for line in read_in_fh:` here you are taking each letters in the string thats why you are not getting the desired output. so iwrote something first to transform the string into a list. while doing that i also eliminated `""` and `''` as you mensioned. then wrote it in to a new file `example.txt`.

Note: change the file name according to your files

```
read_out_fh = open('file.txt',"r")
for line in read_out_fh:
    line=line.strip("[]").replace('"','').replace("'",'').split(", ")
    with open("example.txt", "w") as output:
        for word in line:
            #print(word)
            output.write(word+'\n')
```

**example.txt(outputfile)**

```
blah.txt
blah1.txt
blah2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below works out for your example you gave in the question:

```
# Content of textfile.txt:
    asdasdasd=["'blah.txt'", "'blah1.txt'", "'blah2.txt'"]asdasdasd


# Code:

import re

read_in_fh = open('textfile.txt',"r")
write_out_fh = open('out_path.txt', "w")


for line in read_in_fh:


    find_list = re.findall(r'\[(".*?"*)\]', line)


    for element in find_list[0].split(","):

        element_formatted = element.replace('"','').replace("'","").strip()

        write_out_fh.write(element_formatted + "\n")


write_out_fh.close()
```